# Why does the location of saver in the script matter when there is a graph object in TensorFlow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I was training some models and I noticed that when I explicitly defined a graph variable, then it mattered where my saver object was created. First my code looked like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("tmp_MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([784, 10], mean=0.0, stddev=0.1),name='w')
b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[10]),name='b')
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1)) # list of booleans indicating correct predictions
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.2).minimize(cross_entropy)
saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(1001):
        batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
        sess.run(fetches=train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
        if i % 100 == 0:
            saver.save(sess=sess,save_path='./tmp/mdl_ckpt')
    print(sess.run(fetches=accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}))
```

then I decided to change it to something like this and it seemed very sensitive where I defined my variables and where I defined saver. If they were not defined exactly after the graph variable was created for example, it would have errors. Similarly, I noticed that saver had to be defined exactly after one single variable (note being after the definition of the graph was **not** enough) for all the variables to be captured together by the saver (which didn't make sense to me, it would make more sense to require that its behind the definition of **all** the variables rather than a single one for this to work).

This is how the code looks now (with comments showing the locations of where I've defined saver):

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("tmp_MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

graph = tf.Graph()
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    #saver = tf.train.Saver()
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
    #saver = tf.train.Saver()
    W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([784, 10], mean=0.0, stddev=0.1),name='w')
    #saver = tf.train.Saver()
    b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[10]),name='b')
    y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)
    #saver = tf.train.Saver()
    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1)) # list of booleans indicating correct predictions
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)
    #saver = tf.train.Saver()
    step = tf.Variable(0, name='step')
    #saver = tf.train.Saver()
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    #saver = tf.train.Saver()
    for i in range(1001):
        batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
        sess.run(fetches=train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
        if i % 100 == 0:
            step_assign = step.assign(i)
            sess.run(step_assign)
            saver.save(sess=sess,save_path='./tmp/mdl_ckpt')
    print(step.eval())
    print( [ op.name for op in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES)] )
    print(sess.run(fetches=accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}))
```

the code above should work, but I am having a hard time understand why it behaves like this or why it makes sense that this would happen. Someone know what the right thing to do is?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what's going on here, but I suspect the issue is related to variables not going into the wrong graph, or the session having an outdated version of the graph. You create a graph, but don't set it as the default, then create a session with that graph... but when you create variables, you don't specify which graph they should go into. Maybe the creation of the session sets the specified graph to the default, but that's not the way tensorflow was designed to be used, so I wouldn't be surprised if it hasn't been thoroughly tested in this regime.

While I don't have an explanation or what's going on, I can suggest a simple solution: separate graph construction with session running.

```
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    build_graph()
    saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    do_stuff_with(sess)
    saver.save(sess, path)
```

Comment: but the weird thing is that it just needs to be defined as the first variable, why is the requirement after all the variables?

Comment: sorry, thought the indent was a `with graph.as_default`, not a session creation. Updated answer... hope it helps, even if it doesn't answer the question directly...

Comment: awesome suggestion! Definitively 1000 times less confusing. When you say "that's not the way tensorflow was desgined to be used", do you mind clarifying that? Or providing a link? I am very interested in understanding how tensorflow is supposed to be used (to maybe design my code better or use it better, who knows)

Comment: I was going to ask you, how do the variables know which graph they are supposed to be added? is `graph.as_default()` the only way to do it?

Comment: now that I actually tried implementing your idea it seems its not as simple as I thought, because now when I tray to evaluate simple stuff like accuracy etc, the session (or at least python) doesn't know what the variables x,y,y_ etc are so it has a hard time actually evaluating stuff :( do you have any recommendation for this issue?

Comment: Tensorflow always has a default graph, and if you only build 1 graph you don't have to worry too much about the `graph.as_default()` part. I just like to in case I have to extend to multiple graphs later. `Session()` without a graph argument will use the default graph anyway, so in a simple example it's probably just an unnecessary complication. As for python not knowing about `x`, `y` etc., if you created them in the `build_graph()` but didn't return them, you'll have issues. Either return them from the function, or copy+paste your graph generation code in place ot the `build_graph()` func